# SAS: Wildcard characters in IF statements

Tags: sas

I have a dataset with patient diagnosis codes, and I need to use wildcard characters to categorize their diagnoses.

```
patientID diagnosis cancer age gender 
1         250.0      0     65    M     
1         250.00     1     65    M     
2         250.01     1     23    M     
2         250.02     0     23    M     
3         250.11     0     50    F     
3         250.12     0     50    F
4.        513.01.    1     34    M
```

Diagnoses with the 5th character as 0 or 2 need to be classified as type 2 diabetes, and those ending in 1 and 3 need to be classified as type 1 diabetes. However, 250.0 only has 4 characters and needs to be classified as type 2.

This in the data step doesn't work

```
if diagnosis_code ='250.%0' then t2dm = 1;
if diagnosis_code ='250.%1' then t1dm = 1;
```

Comment: Does it specifically have to be the fifth character (with an occasional exception) or can it be the last character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for wildcards for that test. Use the colon modifier to test prefix of the code and substr() function to test the 6th character (5th digit).

```
if diagnosis_code='250.0' or
 (diagnosis_code=:'250.' and substr(diagnosis_code,6)='0') then t2dm = 1;
if diagnosis_code=:'250.' and substr(diagnosis_code,6)='1' then t1dm = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Wildcard matches in DATA step if statements can be done using the `PRXMATCH` function.  PRX means Perl regular expression.

`PRXMATCH (`*regular-expression-pattern*`,`*text-to-evaluate*`)`

[PRXMATCH Function](http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lefunctionsref&docsetTarget=n0bj9p4401w3n9n1gmv6tfshit9m.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en) documentation

Sample data

```
data have; input
patientID diagnosis_code $ cancer age gender $; datalines;
1         250.0      0     65    M     
1         250.00     1     65    M     
2         250.01     1     23    M     
2         250.02     0     23    M     
3         250.11     0     50    F     
3         250.12     0     50    F
4.        513.01.    1     34    M
run;
```

Example code

```
data want;
  set have;
  t2dm = prxmatch('/^250\.\d*0$/', trim(diagnosis_code)) > 0;
  t1dm = prxmatch('/^250\.\d*1$/', trim(diagnosis_code)) > 0;
run;
```

Notes for the sample code

- `/` bounds a regex pattern
- `^` match at the beginning
- `250` match 250
- `\.` match an actual period
- `\d` match a digit

  - `\d*` match zero or more digits
- `0` `1` match a 0 or 1

  - `0$` `1$` match the 0 or 1 at the end
- `trim()` trim the text to evaluate so the match at the end works
- `> 0` a match will return position *p* in text or 0 if no match, *p* > 0 will logically evaluate to 0 or 1 and be assigned to the flag variable

Comment: For ICD codes you do not want the `*` after the `\d` since you only want to match a single digit there.

Comment: Indeed, for the case of ICD-9 codes, @ybao may want to utilize a lookup table for validation and or conceptual categorization.  Consider looking into OMOP Vocabularies such as ICD-9-CM.  I would hope ybao is dealing with data sets that are HIPPA compliant and have codes cleansed by the health data provider.

Comment: What is OMAP? Yes this dataset is HIPAA compliant.

Comment: Observational Medical Outcomes Partnership (OMOP). A wide variety of medical information (health related data) is encapsulated within the OMOP Common Data Model (CDM).  The CDM includes data structures for Vocabularies (that enumerate tens if not dozens of coding systems), of which one is ICD-9-CM. See https://www.ohdsi.org/data-standardization/ and http://vocabbuild.omop.org/condition-domain/icd-9-cm.  The vocabularies are common structured versions of information from sources such as  http://www.cms.gov/Medicare/Coding/ICD9ProviderDiagnosticCodes/codes.html